# Is there a name for the technique of using base-2 numbers to encode a list of unique options?

Tags: algorithm, bitmask, bitflags

I am writing a couple of functions that encode and decode a list of options into a Long so they can easily be passed around the application, you know this kind of thing:

> 1 - Apple
> 2 - Orange
> 4 - Banana
> 8 - Plum
> etc.
>
> In this case the number 11 would represent Apple, Orange & Plum.

I've got it working but I see this used all the time so assume there is a common name for the technique, and no doubt all sorts of best practice and clever algorithms that are at the moment just out of my reach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bit Flags. It's a technique used as part of Bitmasking.

0001 - Apple
0010 - Oranage
0100 - Banana
1000 - Plum

Each 1 is the flagged bit.

Now you can easily perform bitwise operations using those number:

```
if((11 & Apple) == Apple) // The Apple Flag is set
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: @Martin - Yes...already changed it before I saw the comment. Good catch though.

Comment: use parens around the bitwise and

Comment: Haven't you got the precedence wrong there?
(9 & Orange == Orange) evaluates to TRUE, where it should be false.
It should be ((9 & Orange) == Orange) which does evaluate to FALSE

Comment: @Andy - Apparently so. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Bit field: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Answer (score 2):

Bitflags

Answer (score 1):

going by the help for the c# [Flags attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(VS.71).aspx)  i'm going to go with a bit field or set of flags

sort of related, in hardware there is also [one-hot encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) though this implies you don't get combinations of flags set